# Why does my paragraph element extend under the adjacent image?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components

My code in react.js using styled components have this p that isn't making the text right

[image]

```
const InnerCarousel = styled.div`
    display: flex; // Use flexbox to center the image
    justify-content: center; // Center horizontally
    align-items: center; // Center vertically
    height: 110vh; // Make sure the card takes the full height of the viewport
`;
const Texts = styled.div`
    padding: 4em;
    max-width: 30vw;
`;
const Images = styled.img`
    min-width: 10vw;
    max-width: 60vw;
    min-height: 10vh;
    max-height: 60vh;
    border-radius: 60px;
    `;
const H1 = styled.h1`
    font-size: 24px;
    `;
const Paragraph = styled.p`
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Mont-serrat', sans-serif;
    max-width: 30vw;
    `;


`;
export default function CarouselHome() {
  return (
    <>
      <Swiper navigation={true} modules={[Navigation]} className="mySwiper">
        <SwiperSlide style={{ height: '80vh' }}>
                <InnerCarousel>
                    <Texts>
                        <H1>eCO Funding</H1>
                        <Paragraph>ParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagrapParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraph </Paragraph>
                    </Texts>
                    <Images src={Image} alt="carousel" />
                </InnerCarousel>
```

I tried making the p text goes to the bottom when hitting the image with max width but it didn't work, I don't know what to do

Comment: Please take the [tour] so you know how to respond to answers. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.

Comment: Then, it can be very difficult to sort out CSS/layout issues from JSX code. Ideally you'd show us the rendered HTML and relevant CSS.

Comment: Finally, do you actually have a word that long? This doesn't seem like a valid scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Word break is a good option but I don't think you are actually going to write one big word without any spaces in actual project.
Right now it's just one word, that's why it's not breaking, but if it behaves the dame way for normal sentences then try this -

```
const Paragraph = styled.p`
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Mont-serrat', sans-serif;
    max-width: calc(30vw - 8em);
    `;
const Texts = styled.div`
    padding: 4em;
    max-width: 30vw;
    overflow: hidden;
`;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You are probably looking for the CSS property `word-break`.

If you set it `word-break: break-all` on your `Paragraph` component it should as you expect.

Check out the documentation for other options for this property.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break